# I need to change the color of only a file from my string

Tags: android, string, text, colors, textcolor

I have the following string:

```
<string name="welcome.location.services">Please <font color='green'>ALLOW</font> Passenger to access your location in order to track your trips.</string>
```

If I leave it like this, it will colour ALLOW with the default green. But I need a different colour there. How can I change it?
Tried:

```
<font color='#ff00ff'>ALLOW</font>
```

But the word will have no colour like this.
I want to do it in the strings.xml cause I have more files for each language, and the words length and start index is different, making spannable strings hard to work with

PS: I tried using HTML.fromHTML but still no luck:

```
((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.header4)).setText(Html.fromHtml(context.getString(R.string.welcome_location_services)));
```

Where the string is:

```
<string name="welcome.location.services">Please <font color='#ffff00d3'>ALLOW</font> Passenger to access your location in order to track your trips.</string>
```

Comment: are you using `Html.fromHtml` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, I set it from the layout file. not programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this, and let me know.

```
String s = "Hello World, I'm the rest.";
 String[] result = s.split(" ", 2);
 String first = result[0];
 String rest = result[1];

 first = "<font color='#EE0000'>red</font>";
 t.setText(Html.fromHtml(first + rest));
```

Comment: this worked, thanks a lot! But after some playing with it, I decided to go with SpannableString, and just set it in the activity, not the xml

Answer (score 0):

From Ahmed's link, I assume this should help, `<string name="title"> My <![CDATA[  <font color="#ae23ee">]] Cool <![CDATA[  </font> ]]  Title</string>`

So here only 'Cool' will be in that colour

Comment: Neither, in my app, I will have a textview that will say, for example: 
"This is my TextView number 1". I want only the word "TextView" to be set in another color., so it will show:
"This is my" and "number 1" in black, but TextView in green.
But if I do it like in the example, then the "TextView" word will have the color as green, but the normal green: 00FF00. I need it in another colour. Is that possible? as in, can I use somehow '#00FF12' instead of 'green' when selecting colour? Or is there another way to do this?
I would prefer to do it in the strings.xml and not in code.

Answer (score 0):

use `CDATA` which used with text data that should not be parsed by the `XML` parser.

use this:

```
<string name="welcome.location.services"><![CDATA[<b><font color=#FF0000>ALLOW!</b>]]></string>
```

For more info about CDATA check out this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp).

Comment: I know about CDATA, but that works for the whole string.
I have a 10 words strings and I only want 1 of them to change the colour, not the entire phrase

Comment: you can define two different strings and then concatenate them together in your code !!

Comment: Yes, was afraid of that. Will do it like that.
My strings file is converted from the Localizable.strings (iOS application strings file). And each time something changes I am getting a new Localizable.strings file. Was hoping I can make it somehow, without needing to change the keys and strings. But apparently I cant. Thanks, will do it with more strings concatenated :)